# Create chart with amcharts using nested Json

Tags: json, amcharts

I need to create a serial chart with AmCharts but I can't get it to plot the nested bySexeDto array's nbre value.

Here's my [JSON structure](https://fiddle.jshell.net/t31ro6h7/).

How do I get AmCharts to plot nested structures?

[image: Desired output]

Comment: i need same thing like this
http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

Comment: MY jSON
https://fiddle.jshell.net/t31ro6h7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AmCharts doesn't look at nested JSON structures when drawing the chart. You have to move the nested array in the `bySexeDto` field into the top level as its own separate element.

Here's an example that takes your array and flattens it into a an array of objects resembling `{"category": "...", "value0": ..., "value1": ...}`

```
//remap the array by flattening it into a compatible AmCharts dataProvider array with a matching categoryField and valueFields for each graph.
//this returns an array of {"category": "...", "value0": ..., "value1": ..., /* etc ... */}
var processedChartData = rawData.map(function(rawDataElement) {
  var newDataElement = { "category": rawDataElement.libelleAr };
  rawDataElement.bySexeDto.forEach(function(nestedElement, index) {
    newDataElement["value" + index] = nestedElement.nbre;
    newDataElement["subcategory" + index] = nestedElement.libelleAr; //for balloonText purposes
  });
  return newDataElement;
});
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/cf1cfdb933bf36a83db69a4f8ba0ebb3?editors=0010)

If you need extra fields from the original array, modify the code to include them in the newDataElement structure.

Comment: The solution is to move the nested value. I'm not sure what else you're asking for.

Comment: the problem is the server generate json like this format :/ but i need to get nbre for chart

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from writing your own JavaScript code that pre-processes the server JSON into the correct format. I updated my answer to show an example.

Comment: Thhhhhhhhhhhhhx bro you are engineer <3

Comment: of course
one more question 
i need to make balloon "balloonText": "[[category1]]  <b>[[value1]]</b>",

Comment: You can't have multiple categories, but I'm assuming you want the sub level's libelleAr values? Modify the forEach to include them but call them something else like subcategory0,1, etc. Demo/answer updated.

Comment: you are not nrml <3 thx one more time 
if you have page fb or any think i can follow you and proud

Comment: i know i question much but i need to make rawData get the json from external URL 
like this : 
var rawData = (function () {
    var rawData = null;
    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': "par_situation_sexe.json",
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function (data) {
            rawData = data;
        }
    });
    return rawData;
})();
but not work :/

Comment: This should be posted as a separate questions since StackOverflow doesn't like long threads and this is more of a general javascript question now. You shouldn't disable async since that's not good practice. You should make the success callback call the function that handles your preprocessing. You'll have to look at your application's structure to figure out the best way to do that for your case. Use your browser's debugger (hit F12), and step through your code to help figure out what isn't working.

Comment: the problem in my application is to separate the json data in external file type json
and call in rawData
pls help me :'(