# Json to Map Unsing Amcharts

Tags: javascript, json, amcharts

I need to creat a Tunisia map using Amcharts with my json data 
Code in my json / id in tunisiaLow
nbre in my json / value in tunisialow
i change in tunisiaLow like my json data but not work 
i need samthink like this
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ny4Z.png)
pleas help me 
this is my code in plunker plnkr.co/edit/6aDJREhcFYSfM5JW99mX?p=preview

Comment: My code : http://plnkr.co/edit/6aDJREhcFYSfM5JW99mX?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest issue with your code is that you modified the AmCharts map JS file in such a way that it completely breaks with the library. The JS files should not be modified unless you know what you're doing and follow the directions on [creating your own map files tutorial](https://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/creating-custom-maps-for-javascript-ammap/). Your modified file removes the required `id` attribute that makes the map function.

Ideally you should modify your data to match the map format, not the other way around. Going by your [last ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43225959/create-chart-with-amcharts-using-nested-json), you seem to be unable to change your data, so the solution is the same as the last - remap your data to conform with AmCharts' format.

The original JS/SVG map has a list of IDs for each province. Since your dataset's titles don't exactly match the titles within the original map, you'll want to create a lookup object that uses your titles to link up to the internal map IDs, for example, using your French titles:

```
  var areaDataMapping = {
    "TUNIS": "TN-11",
    "ARIANA": "TN-12",
    "BEN  AROUS": "TN-13",
    "MANOUBA": "TN-14",
    "NABEUL": "TN-21",
    "ZAGHOUAN": "TN-22",
    "BIZERTE": "TN-23",
    "BEJA": "TN-31",
    "JENDOUBA": "TN-32",
    "KEF": "TN-33",
    "SILIANA": "TN-34",
    "KAIROUAN": "TN-41",
    "KASSERINE": "TN-42",
    "SIDI  BOUZID": "TN-43",
    "SOUSSE": "TN-51",
    "MONASTIR": "TN-52",
    "MAHDIA": "TN-53",
    "SFAX": "TN-61",
    "GAFSA": "TN-71",
    "TOZEUR": "TN-72",
    "KEBILI": "TN-73",
    "GABES": "TN-81",
    "MEDENINE": "TN-82",
    "TATAOUINE": "TN-83"
    };
```

From there, you can remap your parsed JSON file to create the correct area object array with the required properties such as `id`, `title` and `value` and then assign the result to your code:

```
var remappedAreas = AmCharts.parseJSON( areas ).map(function(area) {
  return {
    id: areaDataMapping[area.libelleFr],
    title: area.libelleAr,
    code: area.code,
    value: area.nbre
  }
});
var map = AmCharts.makeChart("...", {
   // ...
   "dataProvider": {
   // ...
   "areas": remappedAreas,
   // ...
   },
   // ...
});
```

Here's an [updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VbdYsZn6rkHPyEBu3l69?p=preview), which uses the official AmCharts JS for Tunisia instead of your version.

Comment: i have one more problem if you can help me please

i have a nested json content government nested with sex men/women , i need to represent two map for each sex  

i need to create two map : map one with color blue show the men nbre and map two with color red how the women nbre 

Link for my Plunker Content nested json and my idea :
http://plnkr.co/edit/DeuufEUbumWL1lR4Ckd5?p=preview

thanks

Comment: Have you tried to make it work yourself? Take the idea from here and the logic from [the last ticket on nested json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43225959/create-chart-with-amcharts-using-nested-json) and make two maps. It's really not that hard.

Comment: When I said to combine the ideas, I didn't mean to literally copy the code from another answer. [Here's what you're looking for](http://plnkr.co/edit/rLB8ruuM41fTP6q5BbgA?p=preview). I highly recommend you go through the code carefully to see what it is doing rather than pasting random pieces of code together and hope it works. Also make sure you're generating valid JSON using your backend technology's JSON serializer method or make sure it properly supports your character set. I was getting errors when using JSON lint to validate your data because the arabic text reversed one of your numbers.

Comment: Thx one more time 
finaly after 6h traied to solve my problem you help me thx <3